# Breeze column based security

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I have a "web forms", "database first enitity" project using Breeze. I have a "People" table that include sensitive data (e.g. SSN#). At the moment I have an IQueryable web api for GetPeople.

The current page I'm working on is a "Manage people" screen, but it is not meant for editing or viewing of SSN#'s. I think I know how to use the BeforeSaveEntity to make sure that the user won't be able to save SSN changes, but is there any way to not pass the SSN#s to the client?

Note: I'd prefer to use only one EDMX file. Right now the only way I can see to accomplish this is to have a "View" in the database for each set of data I want to pass to the client that is not an exact match of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use JSON.NET serialization attributes to suppress serialization of the SSN from the server to the client. See the JSON.NET documention on serialization attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your tables. (For now, this is the only solution that comes to mind.)

Put your SSN data in another table with a related key (1 to 1 relation) and the problem will be solved. (Just handle your save in case you need it.)

If you are using Breeze it will work, because you have almost no control on Breeze API interaction after the user logs in, so it is safer to separate your data. (Breeze is usually great, but in this case it's harmful.)